# Implement search functionality in Jface Treeviewer

Tags: java, treeview, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm trying to implement search functionality in Jface Treeviewer, I have tried using SearchableTreeViewer but it didn't help, I want to highlight all the columns that contain the corresponding text

```
    public void searchTree(String searchtext) {
    
    viewer.collapseAll();
    final int itemCount = viewer.getTree().getItemCount();
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemCount; itemIndex++) {
        TreeItem item = viewer.getTree().getItem(itemIndex);
            if (item.getData().toString().toUpperCase().contains(searchtext.toUpperCase())) {
                viewer.expandToLevel(item.getData(), TreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
                item.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 255, 0, 0));         
            }
            else {
                item.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));   
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Here I'm able to highlight the parent row but what I'm trying to achieve is to highlight the exact column(Symbol Name)

Any idea to highlight the child node specific columns ?

Comment: Using `TreeViewerColumn` with separate label providers is probably the best way. Using `StyledCellLabelProvider` or one of its subclasses allows lots of styling choices. Don't mess with the TreeItems, the viewer owns those and may change them at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do tree.setSelection to that child item before setting the foreground color.